# Php mail() - ¿Como añadir código HTML al mensaje del correo después de un formulario con enctype="multipart/form-data"?

Tags: php, html, formularios, mail

Muy buenas,

A ver si alguien me puede ayudar. Tengo un formulario para enviar un correo adjuntando archivos.

```html
<form name='formulario' class="contact_form" id='formulario' method='post' action='' enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email *</label>
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control">                      
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Asunto *</label>
      <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">                      
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Mensaje *</label>
      <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8" ></textarea>                      
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type='file' name='archivo1' id='archivo1' placeholder="carga tu boucher">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center;">
      <input type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="Enviar">
      <a href="clases.php" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Cancelar</a>                       
   </div>
</form>
```

El problema viene cuando en el cuerpo del mensaje quiero añadir, al final, código HTML para incluir la firma del remitente. Como el formulario incluye **enctype="multipart/form-data**" para poder adjuntar documentos, cuando añado el html, al enviar el correo me lee el código como texto.

```html
$firma = '<table style="border:none;border-collapse:collapse">
   <colgroup>
      <col width="198">
      <col width="402">
   </colgroup>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <p><span><span><img src=""></span></span></p>
         </td>
         <td>
            <p><span>Persona</span></p>
            <p><span>Estudios</span></p>
            <p><span>Titulo</span></p>
            <p><span>Texto</span></p>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <p><a href="" target="_blank"><span><span><img src=""></span></span></a><a href="" target="_blank"><span><span><img src=""></span></span></a></p>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>';

$mensaje .= $firma;

if (mail($para,$subject,$mensaje,$de)) {
    echo "<script language='javascript'>
    alert('Mensaje enviado, muchas gracias.');
    </script>";
} else {
    echo "<script language='javascript'>
    alert('fallado');
    </script>";
}
```

Si suprimo la opción **enctype**, me funciona la firma pero no el archivo adjunto, claro está.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: [El **Ejemplo 4** del Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php) te explica cómo preparar el contenido para enviarlo como HTML, en suma, debes crear un html completo, con al menos las etiquetas: `html, head, body`, poniendo el contenido en el `body` por supuesto  y debes indicar en la cabacera que es contenido HTML. Intenta como se muestra en el ejemplo y nos dices si hay algún problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema se resuelve añadiendo los headers correspondientes al la estructura del mensaje del correo, por ejemplo:

```
<?php
// ...
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
// ...
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semilla_aleatoria}x";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"" . "\r\n";

$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n\r\n";
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
$message .= '<html><head></head><body><p>Mensaje HTML</p></body></html>' . "\r\n";
// ... proceso de adjuntar archivos
// ...
mail(/*... parametros ...*/); // Finalmente enviar correo
```

La siguiente función tiene los conceptos expuestos anteriormente. Es una función genérica, sirve para enviar correo con/sin adjuntos y texto html/plain.

```
<?php
function send_mail($from_name, $from_email, $to, $subject, $msg, $contype, $files=array()) {
    $subject = '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?='; // Para titulo con tildes o enie
    $content = ($contype == "plain") ? "text/plain" : "text/html";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_email.">"."\r\n";
    $headers .= "To: ". $to . "\r\n";
    if(count($files) > 0) { // Si hay elementos para adjuntar
        $semi_rand = md5(time());
        $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"" . "\r\n";
        // multipart boundary
        $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
        $message .= "Content-Type: $content; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
        $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= $msg . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\r\n";
        // preparing attachments
        for($x=0; $x<count($files); $x++) {
            $file = fopen($files[$x], "rb");
            $data = fread($file, filesize($files[$x]));
            fclose($file);
            $chunk_data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
            $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\r\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\r\n" .
            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n" . " filename=\"$files[$x]\"\r\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n" . $chunk_data . "\r\n\r\n";
            $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\r\n";
        }
    } else { // Si no hay elementos para adjuntar, enviar un correo normal
        $headers .= "Content-type: $content; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
        $message = $msg;
    }
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // Envia correo
}
```

La puedes poner a trabajar llamándola, por ejemplo, de la siguiente forma:

```
$fromname = "Nombre Apellido";
$fromemail = "remitente@tu_dominio.com";
$to = "correo_para@su_dominio.com";
$subj = "Asunto del correo";
$msg = '<html><head></head><body>
<h3>T&iacute;tulo del mensaje</h3>
<p>Este es el cuerpo del mensaje</p>
</body></html>';
$files = array('archivo1.pdf', 'archivo2.xlsx');
send_mail($fromname, $fromemail, $to, $subj, $msg, "html", $files);
```

[*] En el 6to argumento, si pones cualquier cosa diferente a `"plain"` lo manda como texto `html`. El argumento `$files` es opcional, y es un array con los nombres de los archivos.

De todas formas, recomiendo el uso de [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) para estos menesteres. Es mucho menos engorroso de ponerlo a trabajar, más intuitivo, no requiere configuración de php.ini y es multi-plataforma.

Referencias - En inglés -
[How to attach two or multiple files and send mail in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22245082/1545868)
[Email from PHP has broken Subject header encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4389676/1545868)

Comment: Ha funcionado perfectamente! Muy claro y extenso, muchas gracias por la ayuda.