# Como enviar un archivo adjunto en una ruta de mi servidor por correo en php

Tags: php, email

Quiero enviar un correo adjunto con unos archivos desde php, para eso tengo en un array "docjson" las rutas de los archivos que quiero enviar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un código de ejemplo que funciona adjuntando archivos y enviando el correo desde un formulario, pero la diferencia con mi problema es que yo ya tengo la ruta del archivo en un array, como podría adecuar el código para que funcione con lo que quiero que es enviar el adjunto desde el array que estoy manejando "docjson":

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>E-mail with Attachment</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){

   // we'll begin by assigning the To address and message subject
   $to="fer.lop.sot@gmail.com";
   $subject="Solicitud de registro de embarque";

   // get the sender's name and email address
   // we'll just plug them a variable to be used later
   $from = stripslashes($_POST['fromname'])."<".stripslashes($_POST['fromemail']).">";

   // generate a random string to be used as the boundary marker
   $mime_boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";

   // now we'll build the message headers
   $headers = "From: $from\r\n" .
   "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
      "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
      " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

   // here, we'll start the message body.
   // this is the text that will be displayed
   // in the e-mail

   $message = "El usuario:".$_POST["fromname"]." Ha solicitado una orden de embarque con los siguientes datos:";

   // next, we'll build the invisible portion of the message body
   // note that we insert two dashes in front of the MIME boundary 
   // when we use it
   $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
      "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
      "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
      "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
   $message . "\n\n";

   // now we'll process our uploaded files
   foreach($_FILES as $userfile){
      // store the file information to variables for easier access
      $tmp_name = $userfile['tmp_name'];
      $type = $userfile['type'];
      $name = $userfile['name'];
      $size = $userfile['size'];

      // if the upload succeded, the file will exist
      if (file_exists($tmp_name)){

         // check to make sure that it is an uploaded file and not a system file
         if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_name)){

            // open the file for a binary read
            $file = fopen($tmp_name,'rb');

            // read the file content into a variable
            $data = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name));

            // close the file
            fclose($file);

            // now we encode it and split it into acceptable length lines
            $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
         }

         // now we'll insert a boundary to indicate we're starting the attachment
         // we have to specify the content type, file name, and disposition as
         // an attachment, then add the file content.
         // NOTE: we don't set another boundary to indicate that the end of the 
         // file has been reached here. we only want one boundary between each file
         // we'll add the final one after the loop finishes.
         $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
            "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
            " name=\"{$name}\"\n" .
            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
            " filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
         $data . "\n\n";
      }
   }
   // here's our closing mime boundary that indicates the last of the message
   $message.="--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
   // now we just send the message
   if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
      echo "Mensaje enviado";
   else
      echo "No se pudo enviar el mensaje";
} else {th
?>
<p>Send an e-mail with an attachment:</p>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" 
   enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">
   <p>Your name: <input type="text" name="fromname"></p>
   <p>Your e-mail: <input type="text" name="fromemail"></p>
   <p>Mod List: <textarea  name="question" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" name="modlist"></textarea>
   <p>File: <input type="file" name="file1"></p>
   <p>File: <input type="file" name="file2"></p>
   <p>File: <input type="file" name="file3"></p>
   <p>File: <input type="file" name="file4"></p>
   <p>File: <input type="file" name="file5"></p>
   <p>File: <input type="file" name="file6"></p>
   <p>File: <input type="file" name="file7"></p>
   <p>File: <input type="file" name="file8"></p>
   <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Repito, el código funciona, pero, desde un formulario, yo quiero hacerlo desde el array que tengo la ruta.

Comment: La función de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/432938/80870) debe servir para enviar los archivos adjuntos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Php mail() - ¿Como añadir código HTML al mensaje del correo después de un formulario con enctype="multipart/form-data"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/432871/php-mail-como-a%c3%b1adir-c%c3%b3digo-html-al-mensaje-del-correo-despu%c3%a9s-de-un-formul)

Comment: gracias por su respuesta, no exactamente en mi lugar yo ya tengo almacenado los archivos en una ruta shipment/shipment872.pdf por ejemplo y necesito enviar los que tenga en mi array, si en mi array tengo 8 se enviarán los 8 adjuntos, si en mi array tengo 1 se enviará solo uno.